# SharePoint SPFx Dynamic Data: Are all the source and consumer web-parts required to be developed in same solution / same folder?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, spfx

I'm going to have a situation in our SP Online Portal where we gonna have different vendors going to develop different "Consumer" Web Parts, consuming from one common "Source" Web Part which is gonna be written by our internal team. All these Web Parts need to connect each other, later on the production. But in the development phase, obviously all of these Web Parts cannot be developed/written in same project solution (or folder) since they are coming as in different "solutions" from different parties.

### Question

Do all *source* and *consumer* Web Parts need to be written altogether **in same solution** / same project folder, in order for them to be "connectable" between each others? If not, how or which element (i.e, "id?") of the source Web Part do the consumers need to use in order to connect to the source Web Part?

Comment: You can ask vendors to share the web part id from `manifests.json` file in web part solution. Let me know if using this id works for you.

Comment: Hi @GaneshSanap does that mean that all these different web parts actually DO NOT need to be developed in the same "solution" package altogether? (which is what I'm hoping for)